# FIND_IN_SET() not working for single value

Tags: mysql

I have table named `post` in which there is a column called `visible_user_ids` in which comma separated values are there. When I display the post by respective user then I used the `FIND_IN_SET()`.

e.g. `FIND_IN_SET('8','visible_user_ids')` it shows the all the records from post table for user id 8 when visible_user_ids column contains comma separated user ids such as

```
3,5,8
8,5
8,1,12
etc.
```

but when visible_user_ids column contain only one value i.e. 8 then it does not display the post table record.

Please suggest a solution. Whether `FIND_IN_SET()` works for single value?

Comment: The query `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('8', '8')` works fine for me and returns `1` as the result set.  You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: In addition to @TimBiegeleisen comment, `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b',' b ');` returns 0. So, probably, you should look for a trimmed string, better even remove any trailing commas.

Comment: @SarathChandra Yes, I suspect the `visible_user_ids` string is bad and has formatting problems.  As Drew mentioned, you should try to keep things normalized if you can.

Comment: with all this time spent, me thinks it is time to normalize your database. Plus you pick up the benefit of index usage. What a concept

Comment: When I hit the static query like below it gives proper result array

SELECT * from post AS p where FIND_IN_SET('8','8') AND (p.status = 2) ORDER BY post_id DESC;

but when use dynamic query like below it does not work properly

SELECT * from post AS p where FIND_IN_SET('8',p.visible_user_ids) AND (p.status = 2) ORDER BY post_id DESC;

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you post the result of the following query in your OP ?
`SELECT *, CONCAT('*',p.visible_user_ids,'*') from post AS p where FIND_IN_SET('8', p.visible_user_ids) AND (p.status = 2) WHERE p.visible_user_ids like '%8%' ORDER BY post_id DESC;`

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` doesn't allow spaces, because they confuse it. So, try `FIND_IN_SET('8', REPLACE(p.visible_user_ids, ' ', '')`.

Comment: i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
FIND_IN_SET('8','visible_user_ids')
```

Try *this*

```
FIND_IN_SET('8',visible_user_ids)
```